# Vue FullPage.js changing Options on method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullpage.js

Using VueFullPage.js by [Alvarotrigo](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/vue-fullpage.js#license)
I created a method for my project that creates a side panel. I'm trying to change an option for FullPage.js when the method is called. I can't figure out how to reference 'options' from the 'methods' section.

Things I've tried:

- I tried using 'this' to reference the option, but I think I'm using 'this' incorrectly.
- $refs.fullpage.api.setAllowScrolling(false); (error: '$refs' is not defined)

Vue Project Script

```
export default {
  components: {
    projOne,
    projTwo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: "projOne",
      options: {
        css3: false,
        autoScrolling: true,
        // eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
        sectionsColor: ["#666666", "#4BBFC3", "#7BAABE", "whitesmoke", "#000"],
        keyboardScrolling: true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: "right",
        navigationTooltips: ["Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3"],
        fitToSection: true,
        continuousVertical: true,
        lazyLoading: true
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openSide: () => {
      let sideNav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
      let Projects = document.getElementById("Projects");

      sideNav.classList.add("activateSide");
      Projects.classList.add("activateProjects");

      //I'm having issue with referencing fullpage_api
      fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false);
      fullpage_api.setAutoScrolling(false);
    },
    closeSide: () => {
      let element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
      let Projects = document.getElementById("Projects");

      element.classList.remove("activateSide");
      Projects.classList.remove("activateProjects");

      //I'm having issue with referencing fullpage_api
      fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
      fullpage_api.setAutoScrolling(true);
    }
  },
};
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import VueFullPage from "vue-fullpage.js";


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueFullPage);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: where do you have fullpage_api declaration written?

Comment: So I'm probably using the wrong syntax as I was building this project in vanilla JS previously.  I think the equivalent to VueFullPage.js is '$refs.fullpage.api'. I try adding in that reference, and I get '$refs' is not defined.

Comment: Also I'm using this documentation. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/vue-fullpage.js#methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [the codepen](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/zpQmwq?editors=1010) provided in the vue-fullpage docs?

You can use `this.$refs.fullpage.[METHOD]()`. In the codepen you can see how the `build` method is called on the `methods` property: `this.$refs.fullpage.build()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue with methods. I added the method change through my v-on:click event. Seemed to accomplish what I was intending.

```
<v-btn v-on:click="openSide(); 
       selectedComponent = 'projOne'; 
       $refs.fullpage.api.setAllowScrolling(false);"
>Open Project 1</v-btn>
```